# Ho do get best features with Spark LinearSVC model?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am trying to use ChiSqSelector to determine the best features for a Spark 2.2 LSVCModel, thus:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelector
val chiSelector = new ChiSqSelector().setNumTopFeatures(5).
   setFeaturesCol("features").
   setLabelCol("label").setOutputCol("selectedFeatures")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(labelIndexer, monthIndexer, hashingTF
   , idf, va, featureIndexer,  chiSelector, lsvc, labelConverter))

val model = pipeline.fit(training)
val importantFeatures = model.selectedFeatures

import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LinearSVCModel
val LSVCModel= model.stages(6).asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.ml.classification.
   LinearSVCModel]

val importantFeatures = LSVCModel.selectedFeatures
```

which gives the error:

```
<console>:180: error: value selectedFeatures is not a member of 
org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LinearSVCModel
   val importantFeatures = LSVCModel.selectedFeatures
```

Is it possible to use ChiSqSelector with this model? If not, is there an alternative?

Comment: You are using wrong model. It is [`ChiSqSelectorModel.selectedFeatures`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelectorModel@selectedFeatures:Array[Int]) not `LinearSVCModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linear SVC will not do any feature selection. You should extract the `ChiSqSelectorModel` from the pipeline, not the `LinearSVCModel`.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelectorModel
val chiSqModel = model.stages(6).asInstanceOf[ChiSqSelectorModel]

val importantFeatures = chiSqModel.selectedFeatures
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: Works great but how do I get the actual features? `selectedFeatures` just gives me some indices.

Comment: @schoon: It will give you the indices of the features in your `features` column. Hence, to know what features were selected you should look on how you constructed the vectors in this column.